# Jquery Selector Class>Child>Child

Tags: jquery, selector

So instead of specifying an id or a class I'd like to hone in on a particular element by using a combination of child elements and class names.

So how could I specify with a jquery selector that I want the first/last child of any center element which is a child of a div with a class name == example?

```
<div class="example">
<center>
<a> <!--I want to be able to select this element -->
<a> <!--or this one -->
</center>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('.example center:first')` and `$('.example center:last')` [Pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this for the first:

```
$('div.example>center>*:first-child');
```

And this for the last:

```
$('div.example>center>*:last-child');
```

You can see a working example here on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/gu126b0n/1/).

Just make sure you really want [Child and not Descendants](https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/).